# mathematical calculations based on edittext field changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 3 edittext fields. (quantity, unit cost and total). When the first(quantity) is filled, if unit cost is entered next, it automatically calculates the total or if the total is entered, it automatically calculates the unit cost. individually, the functions work fine. When I combine them however, i get a stack overflow error

**JAVA CODE:**

```
unit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
            if (qty.matches("")) {

            } else {
                total.setEnabled(false);
                total.setFocusable(false);
                int totalcost = Integer.parseInt(qty) * Integer.parseInt(unit.getText().toString());
                total.setText(Integer.toString(totalcost));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    total.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
            if(qty.matches("")){

            } else{
                unit.setEnabled(false);
                unit.setFocusable(false);
                int unitcost = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString()) / Integer.parseInt(qty) ;
                unit.setText(Integer.toString(unitcost));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

**LogCat:**

```
07-31 03:39:47.640    1623-1623/com.example.Prototype E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.Prototype, PID: 1623
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
        at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:79)
        at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:112)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:182)
        at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
        at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6134)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6032)
        at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6571)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3813)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$3.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:79)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$4.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:105)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$3.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:79)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$4.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:105)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$3.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:79)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$4.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:105)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$3.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:79)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$4.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:105)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.example.Prototype.productsFragmentTab$3.onTextChanged(productsFragmentTab.java:79
```

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError, so in fact when you change a field, then the other one is changed but then as it is changed the other one is changed etc. Infinity loop.

Comment: It's not related with the error but for percision, consider using `BigDecimal` to represent currency fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use additional variable to define is this value change comes from code. For example:

```
    void yourMethod(){
        unit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isChangingByCode = false;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (isChangingByCode){
                    return;
                }
                String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
                if (qty.matches("")) {

                } else {
                    total.setEnabled(false);
                    total.setFocusable(false);
                    int totalcost = Integer.parseInt(qty) * Integer.parseInt(unit.getText().toString());
                    isChangingByCode = true;
                    total.setText(Integer.toString(totalcost));
                    isChangingByCode = false;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        total.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isChangingByCode = false;  
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (isChangingByCode){
                    return;
                }
                String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
                if(qty.matches("")){

                } else{
                    unit.setEnabled(false);
                    unit.setFocusable(false);
                    int unitcost = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString()) / Integer.parseInt(qty) ;
                    isChangingByCode = true;
                    unit.setText(Integer.toString(unitcost));
                    isChangingByCode = false;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maintaining extra variables are never the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setting text on your `TextView` from *inside* your `TextWatcher` is guaranteed to summon an infinite loop. This happens because as soon as you change the text on your TextView, the registered `TextWatcher` gets called, in turn calling your `onTextChanged()` implementation where the text gets set again and so on.

To get around this, simply remove your `TextWatcher` before modifying the text and add it again afterwards. Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {

    ...

    total.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    // Modify text here
    total.addTextChangedListener(this);

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the values in int variables.

Then insert it to a new unitprice variable.

Int a = get price here;

Int b = get quntity;

Int totatl = b*a;

Present to screen: total

String is a complex operation for processing then you want to avoid calculations inside Parse operations. Do the calculations as the type itself.